# OpenGL шейдеры и меши

Tags: opengl, шейдеры, mesh

Есть класс меша. Один шейдер для каждго меша или один шейдер для нескольких мешей? Как корректно это организовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и так и так, как вам будет удобнее.

По хорошему, вводится понятие материала. Материал это совокупность настроек (цвет, свойства) и метода отрисовки (прозрачный, светимый, и т.п.). За 1 тип материалов может отвечать один шейдер.

Составляйте библиотеку шейдеров (например 5 штук), может быть библиотеку материалов (обычно это лишнее) и грузите сколько вам надо мешей (например 1000). Для отрисовки меша используйте подходящий шейдер из библиотеки и передавайте ему параметры материала.

Comment: Ок! В классе меша есть материал. Стало быть, для каждого меша, отображаемого в сцене необходимо загружать шейдер? Другими словами, сколько объектов (мешей) в сцене, столько раз этот (эти) шейдеры загружаются и исполняются?

Comment: Нет же ) Составляйте библиотеку шейдеров (например 5 штук), может быть библиотеку материалов (обычно это лишнее) и грузите сколько вам надо мешей (например 1000). Для отрисовки меша используйте подходящий шейдер из библиотеки и передавайте ему параметры материала.

Comment: Спасибо! Алгоритм приблизительно таков:

Comment: ОтрисовкаМешей()
{
 Шейдер0.Запуск()
  Меш0.Рисовать()
  Меш1.Рисовать()
  Меш2.Рисовать()
 Шейдер0.Стоп()

 Шейдер1.Запуск()
  Меш3.Рисовать()
  Меш4.Рисовать()
  Меш5.Рисовать()
 Шейдер1.Стоп()
}

Comment: Да, можно и так, для уменьшения количества переключений между шейдерами.

Comment: Если у вас много мешей с одинаковыми материалами, то и настройки шейдера можно задать 1 раз перед отрисовкой пачки мешей.

Comment: Так же желательно делать группировку отрисовки по шейдерам, тогда производительность будет выше. Например, включили шейдер1  - отрисовали все меши, которые его используют, и включили шейдер 2 - отрисовали все меши с шейдером2, и тд